docx generated using OpenXml does not show radio buttons and check boxes in MS Word
We use OpenXml to covert html to word. This generated word file does not show radio buttons and check boxes when opened in MS word. It used to show but with recent windows updates, radio buttons and check boxes disappeared.
Html contains form elements().
The same word file when opened in any online word viewer, it shows these.
Is it because of recent windows update? How can fix this? Can anyone help please?
